# Identify predictors for a symptom in a time series

Tags: time-series, predictor, risk

I have a dataset of time series. The analogy for each series is a medical history (2-3 years) of a patient visiting a clinic. It consists of dates and symptoms per visit:

[image]

There are few thousands of patients. Patients have 3-4 visits, and 6-7 unique symptoms (out of ~200 symptoms in data).

I want to find a subset (or a lack of such) of symptoms that can serve as a predictors to future symptoms. How can it be done?